# How to remove all text except one with starts with some word?

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying to remove all text except one in javascript

the idea is do something like

```
//jQuery("someelement").attr("class"); 
var classes=  "cnode_1 timestamp_1413504000 item"; 

classes = classes.replace(/^(?!timestamp_)/,'');
```

i want to take only the text who starts with timestamp_, the expected ouput is :

```
timestamp_1413504000
```

i want this , then to grab the number

```
//now "classes" show be timestamp_1413504000
classes = classes.replace("timestamp_","");
```

the expected ouput is :

```
1413504000
```

i want to avoid use something like, split the clasess base on space, then use for bucle, and finally compare with indexOf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the "timestamp_" for something?

Why not just

```
= classes.replace(/^.*timestamp_(\d+).*/img, "$1");
```

Comment: That is what my response does.  Did you try it? If it works, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: yeap it does, i was just answering your question that was in your answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.match` to get the part you want.

```
var classes=  "cnode_1 timestamp_1413504000 item"; 

// match will return the matched string and the groups in an array
var ts = classes.match(/timestamp_(\d+)/)[1]; // match[1] is the group (\d+)
// 1413504000
```

Comment: this worked for me as well for other scenarios, like if i have more than one timestamp_ , changing it to "/timestamp_(\d+)/g" , retrive an array with all the timestamp_ , thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that you want to avoid splitting or using indexOf, but javaScript doesn't have a 'startsWith' function.  Why do you want to avoid doing that?  Is the following unacceptable?

```
var NumberOutput;
var classList = document.getElementById('elementYouAreLookgingAt').className.split(/\s+/);
for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
   if (classList[i].indexOf("someClass") == 0) {
     NumberOutput = classList[i].replace("someClass", "");
   }
}
```